# Why do i get "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" error on execution?

Tags: python, sockets, get, http-headers, httprequest

So i want to send (through a proxy) a request to a website.. The script looks like this and its made with the socket library in python:

```
import socket

TargetDomainName="www.stackoverflow.com"
TargetIP="151.101.65.69"
TargetPort=80
ProxiesIP=["107.151.182.247"]
ProxiesPort=[80]

Connect=f"CONNECT {TargetDomainName} HTTP/1.1"
Connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Connection.connect((ProxiesIP[0],ProxiesPort[0]))
Connection.sendto(str.encode(Connect),(TargetIP, TargetPort))
Connection.sendto(("GET /" + TargetIP + " HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'), (TargetIP, TargetPort))
Connection.sendto(("Host: " + ProxiesIP[0] + "\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'), (TargetIP, TargetPort))
print (Connection.recv(1028))
Connection.close()
```

My question is why i get the 400 bad request error?

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate whether the 400 reply is coming from the proxy or the target server. But both of your commands are malformed.

- Your `CONNECT` command is missing a port number, a `Host` header since you are requesting HTTP 1.1, and trailing line breaks to terminate the command properly.
- Your `GET` command is sent to the target server (if `CONNECT` is successful) and should not be requesting a resource by IP address. It is also sending the wrong value for the `Host` header. The command is relative to the target server, so it needs to specify the target server's host name.

Also, you should be using `send()`/`sendall()` instead of `sendto()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```py
import socket

TargetDomainName="www.stackoverflow.com"
TargetIP="151.101.65.69"
TargetPort=80
ProxiesIP=["107.151.182.247"]
ProxiesPort=[80]

Connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Connection.connect((ProxiesIP[0], ProxiesPort[0]))
Connection.sendall((f"CONNECT {TargetDomainName}:{TargetPort} HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode("ascii"))
Connection.sendall((f"Host: {TargetDomainName}:{TargetPort}\r\n\r\n").encode("ascii"))
print (Connection.recv(1028))

Connection.sendall(("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'))
Connection.sendall((f"Host: {TargetDomainName}\r\n").encode('ascii'))
Connection.sendall(("Connection: close\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'))
print (Connection.recv(1028))

Connection.close()
```

You really need to read the proxy's reply *before* sending the `GET` command. The proxy will send its own HTTP reply indicating whether it successfully connected to the target server or not.

You really should not be implementing HTTP manually though, there are plenty of HTTP libraries for Python that can handle these details for you. Python even has one built-in: [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#module-http.client)

Comment: I tried what you suggested.. Here is the whole error : b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: nginx/1.20.0\r\nDate: Sun, 03 Apr 2022 21:58:28 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 157\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n' I think the error comes from the website though cause the proxy just passes the request to the website.. since i've used the CONNECT method.. maybe am wrong though

Comment: @Petrakous since you are sending both commands at the same time, there is no way to know which server sent the error. You need to send ONLY the CONNECT command first, THEN READ A REPLY, then send the GET command ONLY if the CONNECT command was successful.

Comment: I am creating manual http requests because i want to add custom headers at some point.. but im still stuck here

Comment: @Petrakous pre-existing HTTP libraries let you send custom headers. Don't implement HTTP manually, it is more complex than beginners think it is.

Comment: Im almost certain that the requests pass to the website cause i have used this script in a ddos (dos) program and i could see my website crash.. so i guess if the requests never made it to the website then it wouldnt crash in the first place right?